# Creating class for circle, ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, geometry, shapes

It's my second question about creating geometric shapes via classes.

So, I want to create a circle.

1. First of all I create a class Point
2. Then - create a class Line, using two points (this will be our diameter)
3. Now we have to calculate the distance between this points (diameter)
4. Then we create class Circle
5. And using diameter to create a circle

Hope, so far so good. But when i get to coding i meat some troubles.

Creating class Point:

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize
    @x = 10
    @y = 10
  end
end
```

Then, class Line:

```
class Line
  attr_accessor :p1, :p2
  def initialize
    @p1 = Point.new
    @p2 = Point.new
  end
  def distance
    @distance = Math::sqrt((@p2.x - @p1.x) ** 2 + (@p2.y - @p1.y) ** 2) # -> rb.16
  end
end
```

And in Line class the problems starts. As you understand I want to define method to calculate distance between points in the Line class. Thnx to google search the formula for calculating is:

square root from ((point_2.x - point_1.x)**2 + (point_2.y - point_1.y)**2)

```
#points
point_01 = Point.new
point_01.x = 20
point_02 = Point.new
point_02.x = 10

#line
d = Line.new
d.p1 = point_01
d.p2 = point_02
dis = d.distance # -> rb.40
print dis
```

But it puts me an error:

```
rb:16:in `distance': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

rb:40: in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What are this errors, what they mean?

And the next step will be to calculate circumference (C) with formula:

C = Pi * Diameter

Is that right?

```
class Circle
  attr_accessor :diametr, :c
  def initialize
    @diametr = Line.new
  end
  def circle_length
    return @c = @diametr * Math::PI
  end
end
#circle
circle = Circle.new
circle.diametr = d
res = circle.circle_length
```

Please note that I'm only studying and it may be a silly question but still I don't understand it.

Thank for your help!

Yeah, thnx to the comment below, the error appears Circle class, after using formula to calculate circumference. can you help me with this.

Comment: I ran your code and I'm not getting the `rb:16:in distance': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)` error.

Comment: Why do you need anything other than the center Point and the radius to identify a Circle?

Comment: @Keith Bennett and how we can create a circle without radius?

Comment: Is it that you start out with a line and you have to create the circle that would have it as its diameter?

Comment: @AndreyDrozdov I don't understand.  I was suggesting that a circle can be identified by its center point *and* its radius.

Comment: @Keith Bennett yes, i start with a point, then creating a line (line - two points connected), and from line (we will call it diameter) i want to create a circle

Comment: @Keith Bennett now i don't understand you :) can you suggest other way to build circle?)

Comment: @AndreyDrozdov A circle can be identified by its center and radius...however, if your use case requires building a circle in a certain way (point -> line -> circle) then my point is not useful. ;)  I guess it also depends on how that circle will be used.  Is it theoretical/mathematical only?  Or does it need to be rendered on a screen?  And if so, with which graphical library?  I think most would only need a center and radius.

Comment: @Keith Bennett no, no, it's an assignment what my mentor give me in code-school. We are learning basic of OOP in ruby, and the task is only theoretical: 1st task it was to build circle, 2nd to build line, 3rd to build square or triangle, 4th to build circle, and 5th to build sector(i don't know how it will be in english) from circle

Comment: @Keith Bennett can i ask you a question, how can i create a circle from a radius, if i will calculate circumference, it will not give command to ruby to create circle. All what i will have - circumference. How can i give command to ruby, that line is curve, but not a strait. For example if i will create 4 point on coordinates and connect it together - it will be a square. How can i connect them with curve?

Comment: I'm not aware of any libraries built into Ruby that render graphics on a screen.  What are you using for that?  Which classes/methods do you use to draw lines and shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and I'm not getting the `rb:16:in distance': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)` error.

The `circle_length` method does throw an error and it's because you are trying to multiply `@diameter`, which is an instance of `Line`.

To do that, you need to implement `*` for `Line`:

```
class Line
  def *(other)
    distance * other
  end
end
```

---

Further explanation about what is going on here:

`*` is like any other method in ruby, with some special syntax. When you do `4 * 5`, you're calling the `*` method on `4` (which is just another ruby object, an instance of `Integer`), and passing `5` as its argument. The above code implements/defines a method `*` for `Line`, essentially the same way Integer also implements the method `*`.

It takes a number as an argument and returns the result of multiplying the result of the `distance` method by the argument.

Comment: not sure what code what you wrote means? and how i can call this method later?

Comment: `*` is like any other method in ruby, with some special syntax. When you do `4 * 5`, you're calling the `*` method on 4 (which is just another ruby object, and instance of `Integer`), and passing 5 as it's argument. The code I wrote implements/defines a method `*` for `Line` essentially the same way Integer also implements the method `*`. It takes a number as an argument and returns the result of multiplying it's distance attribute by the number.